# Exiting a shell-script at the end with a non-zero code if any command fails

Tags: bash, shell, sh, exit

I am making a shell script that runs a bunch of tests as part of a CI pipeline.  I would like to run all of the tests (I DO NOT WANT TO EXIT EARLY if one test fails).  Then, at the end of the script, I would like to return with a negative exit code if any of the tests failed.

Any help would be appreciated.  I feel like this would be a very common use case, but I wasn't able to find a solution with a bit of research.  I am pretty sure that I don't want `set -e`, since this exits early.

My current idea is to create a flag to keep track of any failed tests:

```
flag=0
pytest -s || flag=1
go test -v ./... || flag=1
exit $flag
```

This seems strange, and like more work than necessary, but I am new to bash scripts.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What you have is a good approach. What is failing in it? Replace `$flag` with just `flag`.

Comment: How are the tests run? in a loop?

Comment: use `... || flag=1` (no need for `$`)

Comment: It seems excessively wordy to have to specify this for every single line in the script.  Right now, I'm only running a few commands, but I am afraid that this won't scale well if more tests are added in the future.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!  I made the edits.  I am not running the tests in a loop.

Comment: You could probably define a helper function: `chk() { "$@" || flag=1; }` and then do `chk pytest -s; chk go test -v ...`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way would be to catch the non-zero exit code via `trap` with `ERR`. Assuming your tests don't contain pipelines `|` and just return the error code straight to the shell launched, you could do

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exitCodeArray=()

onFailure() {
    exitCodeArray+=( "$?" )
}

trap onFailure ERR

# Add all your tests here

addNumbers () {
    local IFS='+'
    printf "%s" "$(( $* ))"
}
```

Add your tests anywhere after the above snippet. So we keep adding the exit code to the array whenever a test returns a non-zero return code. So for the final assertion we check if the sum of the array elements is `0`, because in an ideal case all cases should return that if it is successful. We reset the `trap` set before

```
trap '' ERR

if (( $(addNumbers "${exitCodeArray[@]}") )); then
    printf 'some of your tests failed\n' >&2
    exit -1
fi
```

Comment: Why do we need the array here?  Why not use a simple integer in `onFailure` that sums up the exit codes?

Comment: @codeforester: Good catch! If I remember right, I wanted the array, so that if needed we can print the array to see the status of individual tests from the start and map each test with its exit code. If one doesn't need that, you could use a variable

Answer (score 2):

I vote for Inian's answer. Traps seem like the perfect way to go.

That said, you might also streamline things by use of arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

testlist=(
  "pytest -s"
  "go test -v ./..."
)

for this in "${testlist[@]}"; do
  $this || flag=1
done

exit $flag
```

You could of course fetch the content of the array from another file, if you wanted to make a more generic test harness that could be used by multiple tools. Heck, [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) could be a good way to populate an array.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could imagine using *less* code is if the shell had some sort of special `all` compound command that might look something like

```
# hypothetical all command
all do
  pytest -s
  go test -v ./...
done
```

whose exit status is the logical `or` of the exit statuses of the contained command. (An analogous `any` command would have the logical `and` of its commands' exit statuses as its own exit status.)

Lacking such a command, you current approach is what I would use. You could adapt @melpomene's suggestion of a `chk` function (which I would call *after* a command rather than having it call your command so that it works with arbitrary shell commands):

```
chk () { flag=$(( flag | $? )); }

flag=0
pytest -s; chk
go test -v ./...; chk
exit "$flag"
```

---

If you aren't using it for anything else, you could abuse the `DEBUG` trap to update `flag` before each command.

```
trap 'flag=$((flag | $?))' DEBUG
pytest -s
go test -v ./...
exit "$flag"
```

(Be aware that a debug trap executes *before* the shell executes another command, not immediately *after* a command is executed. It's possible that the only time this matters is if you expect the trap to fire between the last command completing and the shell exiting, but it's still worth being aware of.)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the hypothetical `all` command to be the logical AND, and the `any` command to be the OR? Or did I somehow read that wrong?

Comment: I'm using `all` to mean "all must succeed", not "all must fail". For example, four exit statuses of 0, 0, 1, and 0 should produce a 1 (the block fails if any command fails).